Правильно ли я написал html разметку по БЭМ?
Правильно ли написано с учетом того, что размещение блоков в css буду делать флексами?



<section class="expertise">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">our expertise</div>
    <div class="expertise__content">
      <div class="expertise__content-top">
        <div class="expertise__content-top-item">
          <div class="expertise__item-results">
            <h3 class="expertise__item-title">branding</h3>
            <span class="expertise__item-percent">90%</span>
          </div>
          <div class="expertise__item-results">
            <h3 class="expertise__item-title">design</h3>
            <span class="expertise__item-percent">80%</span>
          </div>
          <div class="expertise__item-results">
            <h3 class="expertise__item-title">development</h3>
            <span class="expertise__item-percent">85%</span>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="expertise-item-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima porro, rem eveniet vero veniam quibusdam
          dolores, nostrum perferendis laborum laudantium pariatur repellat possimus, tempore fugit necessitatibus
          cupiditate obcaecati nisi distinctio.
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="expertise__content-down">
        <div class="expertise__item">
          <img class="expertise__item-img" src="" alt="">
          <div class="expertise__item-box">
            <div class="expertise__item-title">graphic design</div>
            <div class="expertise__item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quo eos
              dolore ea facere reprehenderit, fugit error consequatur reiciendis cupiditate saepe iste asperiores
              aliquid consectetur quae explicabo beatae magnam praesentium?</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise__item">
          <img class="expertise__item-img" src="" alt="">
          <div class="expertise__item-box">
            <div class="expertise__item-title">web development</div>
            <div class="expertise__item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quo eos
              dolore ea facere reprehenderit, fugit error consequatur reiciendis cupiditate saepe iste asperiores
              aliquid consectetur quae explicabo beatae magnam praesentium?</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise__item">
          <img class="expertise__item-img" src="" alt="">
          <div class="expertise__item-box">
            <div class="expertise__item-title">marketing</div>
            <div class="expertise__item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quo eos
              dolore ea facere reprehenderit, fugit error consequatur reiciendis cupiditate saepe iste asperiores
              aliquid consectetur quae explicabo beatae magnam praesentium?</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>



